# Use IF statement on Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, eloquent

there is a way to use a IF statement on eloquent?

I have one table called 'invoices'  ..

```
invoices(invoiceId,debt,status)
```

Status represents if the invoice is payed or not, and debt is the debt on the invoice.
I'm asking if there is a quick way to update status in such a way that when I make a payment..

```
if invoice.debt = 0 then invoice.status = 0
else invoice.status = 1
```

I'm using laravel 5.3. Thank You!

Comment: Is the basic-looking code supposed to be pseudo code?

Comment: Yes haha, A friend tells me that I could use a trigger but there isn't a way with eloquent?

Comment: Eloquent is an ORM, triggers live on the database!?!?!?! 2 different animals

Comment: Yes, but you can use a migration to create a trigger in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're going in right way,

You can simply do this as:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find(1);
$status = ($invoice->debt == 0) ? 0 : 1;

$invoice->status = $status;
$invoice->save();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works! but was necesary to add this on the model
`public $timestamps = false;`

Comment: If you found this helpful then please accept and upvote the answer as it motivates me to answer other questions like this and help others to find the right answer quickly...

Answer (score 0):

Use [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators).

```
public function setDebtAttribute($debt)
{
    $this->attributes['debt'] = $debt;
    $this->attributes['status'] = $debt ? 1 : 0;
}
```